# Is it worth placing functions, variables, settings etc in different files?

Tags: python

I have this script I'm working on which is some 2,000 lines. At the top I have a list of settings to be used in the script, then all the functions, then the script itself.

I found myself going back and forth from the actual script to the functions (and the settings) so I thought it might be a good idea to place them in separate files, to be imported in the main script, with the practical benefit of being able to open them in different windows, for ease of access.

Is this approach of any value? or, is there any problem with this, maybe in the long term, when the script grows even more? or is it all down to personal preference?

(if it matters, I'm using Python.)

Comment: I work with Eclipse, where I can open the same file few times. Do what ever makes it easier FOR YOU to work and deploy this project

Comment: It is mostly personal preference. I usually have bigger projects and split things into small pieces, but if the choice is between having only one or two files, I find it cool to have everything in one file.

Comment: Anything that you can reuse or would recopy into another script is game for import.  I personally find it easier to maintain one version in a folder within my python path than slightly different incarnations in different scripts and/or projects.

Comment: One single file or many files does not really matters in Python except if some parts could be re-usable in other projects. What matters is the internal organization: is it testable? can you encapsulate functionalities in classes? is it clearly documented? etc.

Answer (score 1):

#### Let's put it this way:

If you are making a big jig saw puzzle, you start dividing the pieces into sections; clouds with clouds, water with water, grass with grass etc. Subsequently, you don't mix the pieces, but put each of the sections into a different corner on the table.

---

Likewise, if you have bigger coding projects, you start separating data from code, create functions and classes to organize your code in a way that makes sense, according to their functionality. If the project is big enough, put different sections into different files (modules).

This is not only to limit the scrolling through possibly thousands of lines, but also to keep your mind clean for the section you are working on, and to make the project *maintainable*.

Last but not least; working this way, most likely at a certain point you will find yourself writing modules, to be reused in other projects.